# pipenv install error for certain python libraries

Tags: python, pipenv

My python project depends on a module named levenshtein which is best installed using

```
sudo apt install python3-levenshtein
```

I generally use pipenv for all my projects but running below command fails in this case:

```
pipenv install levenshtein
```

This causes issues in smooth production deployment. How do I get pipenv to install this/such libraries?

Note - However, install other libraries (such as flask) succeeds using pipenv install using same method.

Screenshot of levenshtein library install error
[image: Screenshot of levenshtein library install error:]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this, but realize the importance now that you mention. Shall certainly take care next time @Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've to use this command.

```
pipenv install python-Levenshtein
```

Comment: Thats correct. Your commands works on this specific example. However, how to make it work for other similar libraries such as opencv? Using pipenv install python3-opencv or pipenv install python-opencv or pipenv install python3-opencv2 or pipenv install python-opencv2 or pipenv install cv2 gives an error!!!

Comment: @Chris - This link is useful. After going through the link, I used  "pipenv install opencv-python" and finally got it to work. Thanks.